# DTMF monitoring via multimon, awk and espeak

Tags: linux, bash, telephony, dtmf

- How to listen to the spoken DTMD digit every time the sound card capture one?

The objective is radio controlling my pc and interfaces activities dialing dtmf tones via a hand-held transceiver.

I used multimon to hear DTMF tones
I tried to use awk to filter digits and proceed accordingly.
For example, if I key "0" from the radio the system must reboot, etc, but first confirming the operation. " The computer will reboot, send # to confirm"...

I tried to use espeak for a voice confirmation to the remote radio.
The radio connected to the pc soundcard receives the commands and transmits the responses.

I do not simply know how to nest multimon within awk within espeak.

Multimon itself doesnt let me do anything with its stdout because its running ( do not terminate after hearing a digit, which is indeed right).

It would be extremely helpful if I knew how to just speak each digit, without exiting the natural multimon loop.

Say, multimon -a DTMF | awk'{print}' espeak -stdin
If this simply worked!

Is it possible to do? Any help wellcome.

3 years passed and still no advance in linux DTMF decoding.

Once I didn't see any DTMF Radio Controlling project in Linux, I plan to publish this shall I can solve this issue.

Comment: Instead of the software stack you're using now, I would use Asterisk; sound card support, DTMF detection, text-to-speech, and the other components you need are all available or included.

Comment: Thanks! I guess asterix is too much for me. I feel I'm almost there, lacking a magic word!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that my answer is out of date and perhaps you have found how to solve this.

I faced the same issue and figured out that the problem is in multimon. When you pipe the stdout from multimon to another program, multimon does not flush the verbose output properly.

Try to patch and recompile multimon, adding a "fflush(stdout);", like this:

(unixinput.c , around line 71 )

```
    void verbprintf(int verb_level, const char *fmt, ...)
    {
            va_list args;

            va_start(args, fmt);
            if (verb_level <= verbose_level) {
                    vfprintf(stdout, fmt, args);



                    fflush(stdout); //ADD THIS LINE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!



                    }
            va_end(args);
    }
```

Best regards,

-Eduardo

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to monitor its output with a perl script and this worked perfectly for me, cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `system()` function to launch `espeak` from your `awk` script.

Comment: Thanks, I will study this function. Do you have a simple example for a short minded me?

Comment: I'd like to comment that multimon outputs texts in the terminal. It decodes well the DTMF tones, I read the outputs ( DTMF 1, DTMF 2, etc) but cannot grab this output text! It renders useless.

Answer (score 0):

@OP, i am not clear about your question, but seeing that system() interests you, here's how you call external command in awk

```
multimon -a DTMF | awk '{
  cmd="espeak "$0 #$0 comes from the multimon output
  system(cmd)
}
'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I believe this is the magic word! Now I'm stuck with another problem: multimon itself refuses to instal on PCLINUXOS (manually or via synaptic - not in repos), so I had to get back to ubuntu to try your answer. Downloading now. I ll be back with the result.

Comment: Eduardo,I must thank you, your answer is not outdated. Indeed, I I had to park the Linux Remote Control Project for God knows how long... until your comming along.

I was to go back to windows to hear the tones, and hide this shame in some computer under some table.

Now I have another issue: how to implement your solution? My knowledge hovers over software, I do some scripting and never compiled a PC software(well, I compiled to PIC microprocessors). Do you have this new multimon ready for use? Or a ladies recipy, step by step, on how to compile it? I really don't know if it's too much to ask

Comment: , but now that you ressurected my hopes I would start making promises to make the project go into life again.

Anyway, thanks for the time taken. Shall I solve it I will publish a big credit to you.